# Why am I getting 'Name collision between ...' errors and how can I fix them?

Tags: shell, vim, emacs, gnu-screen

Every time I try to launch `vim` or `emacs` or even `top` (I think it's actually any command that uses ncurses) in a unix terminal (on a cluster computer over ssh), I get a a continuous stream of 'Name collision between x x x' errors like this:

```
Name collision between dumb dumb
Name collision between unknown unknown
Name collision between lpr lpr
Name collision between glasstty glasstty
Name collision between vanilla vanilla
Name collision between ansi+local1 ansi+local1
Name collision between ansi+local ansi+local
......
Name collision between terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200 terminet1200
Name collision between h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a h19-a
Name collision between h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs h19-bs
Name collision between h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us h19-us
Name collision between h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19 h19
......
```

According to some research I've done on the web this should be related to TERMCAP/TERMINFO, and I think this started happening after I used GNU screen. And in fact, when I am inside a GNU screen session, vim and emacs work fine (except some strange key mappings, for instance arrow keys don't work)

I've tried to set the TERMCAP environment variable to a non-existing file, as I've read somewhere on the internet, and it caused vim to work (with different settings than my usual ones) but not emacs...

Do you know what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: What unix variant are you using? If Linux, what distribution? (If you don't know, post the output of `uname -a`.)

Comment: Here's the output: Linux [host] 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Aug 26 18:49:02 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You probably have duplicated terminfo/termcap libraries. Do this: run "strace -o xxx emacs -nw" and immediately exit emacs. Then open the file xxx and search for the error message. A couple of lines above you should see which term* libraries were opened; there are probably your duplicated terminal entries.

Comment: Thanks, I saw in the trace that it was trying to open some libraries in the Enthought Python Distribution lib folder, which had nothing to do with emacs, so I remembered I had added that folder to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (it's the only way I know to run some compiled code using specific shared libraries...)

Answer (score 4):

Solved:
The problem was I had specified in my `~/.bashrc` an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that contained a folder with many shared libraries, some of which were probably duplicates of others. I think in my case it was the `ncurses` libraries.

Comment: you don't write how to circumvented it: did you just put the EPD libs at the end of LD_LIBRARY_PATH?